# payment gateway

Tags: asp.net, payment-gateway

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I need some guidance on payment gateways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647412/i-need-some-guidance-on-payment-gateways)

hi,

i have a web app.. and need to process credit card payments. Can anyone please recommend the best payment gateway provider that is easy to implement?

Comment: hmm, where do we begin? "subjective/argumentative", "exact duplicate", "not programming related"... vote close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you get an idea of the features you want and run with it.  If the question "is" programming related, then I assume that you're looking for an easy way to integrate your .NET app with the gateway.

Might I suggest [DotNetCharge](http://www.dotnetcharge.com/).

Comment: ok.. what about in term of pricing?

Comment: also how do I test it? is there a mockup credit card that I can use so it won't actually charge?

Comment: The testing is done with whatever gateway you choose.  Really... the number of gateways is nearly endless, and they all have pros/cons.  Just choose one from the supported list in DotNetCharge, and away you go.  Guaranteed they have the ability to "sandbox" your app.

Comment: IMHO - I would not recommend dotnetcharge. I found their product to be sub standard, support rude and documentation poor.

Answer (score 1):

I have used PayPal's 'PayFlowPro' payment gateway.  They have a nice .NET interation via a .dll they have built and it is quite easy to use.  You can learn more about it in the link below:

**Payflow Pro: Online Payment Gateway**
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_payflow-pro-overview-outside

Answer (score 0):

RBS Worldpay have an easy to implement interface.  Passing them information is done with a specially crafted hyperlink and recieving the confirmation of payment from them is done with a request from the RBS system to a web page with certain parameters being passed.  Should take no longer than a couple of hours to get fully working.

They also have a good amount of documentation available on thier support site about how it all works.